# Software Updater Ignores request to update

Tags: updates, update-manager

I have updated to ubuntu 12.10.  Daily I receive notice from the software updater that files are available for updating.  When I click on the "Install Now" button, the clock icon briefly shows, then nothing happens.  The next day I get the same notice showing the same size of download available.  After a couple weeks of this the notice changed to showing twice the size of download available.  This seems to confirm my doubts that no updates are ever installed, they merely accumulate.

How do I get the software update function to perform?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the updates manually. Maybe this is a problem, that will be fixed by on of these updates.

```
sudo -s
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade-y
```

Please keep in mind, that 12.10 will be EOL in april.

Comment: OK, David.  I'll put the time into installing 13.--

Comment: I'd try the manual update like described. If you upgrade, it's even more important to update before.

Comment: Would you recommend going through the upgrade process as opposed to a new or fresh install

Comment: The manual update worked great!  The update manager still will not install updates or upgrades, although it will show a list of updates available.  Is there a terminal command to upgrade to 13.10 - bypassing the update manager?  The update manager offers the suggestion to upgrade to 13.10 but can't seem to get it done.

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: Did it work? Please set as solution. Thanks.